# Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Schema<unknown>'. Yup

Tags: react-native, formik, yup

I not sure am I getting this error , anyone know how to solve this? 
Below is my code the error occur on `extra: Yup.array().of(Yup.lazy((value)....`

```
const claimFormValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape<ClaimApplicationForm>({
  id: Yup.number().notRequired(),
  claimType: Yup.mixed().required(),
  claimAmount: Yup.number().required('Claim Amount is Required'),
  currencyCode: Yup.string().required(),
  rate: Yup.number().required('Rate is Required'),
  convertedAmount: Yup.number().required('Converted Amount is Required'),
  extra: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.lazy((value) => {
      if ('required' in value) {
        if (value.required === true) {
          return Yup.object().shape({
            value: Yup.string().required(),
          });
        } else {
          return Yup.object().shape({
            value: Yup.string().notRequired(),
          });
        }
      }
    }),
  ),
});
```

Error:

> Argument of type '(value: unknown) => ObjectSchema> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown) => Schema'.
>     Type 'ObjectSchema> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Schema'.
>       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Schema'.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the `extra` property

```
  extra: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.lazy((value) => {
      // outter if
      if ('required' in value) {
        if (value.required === true) {
          return Yup.object().shape({
            value: Yup.string().required(),
          });
        } else {
          return Yup.object().shape({
            value: Yup.string().notRequired(),
          });
        }
      }          
      // end outter if

      // if reaches here, nothing is returned
    }),
  ),
```

You need to return something inside `Yup.lazy`, but if this condition isn't true `'required' in value`, you won't return anything, giving you `undefined` and that error.

I'm not sure what you need to return, but it must be something.

Answer (score 1):

After some time , i got what i expect to do.

```
extra: Yup.array().of(
  Yup.lazy((data: any) => {
    if ('required' in data) {
      if (data.required === true) {
        return Yup.object().shape({
          value: Yup.string().required(),
        });
      } else {
        return Yup.object().shape({
          value: Yup.string().notRequired(),
        });
      }
    }
  }),
),
```

I solve this problem by setting the schema for 'extra' like this.

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm